# WPF : how to set an enable look on a disable checkbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I want to use a disabled textbox which will look like an enabled one.

What do I have to add to this XAML ?

```
<CheckBox IsEnabled="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to options here:

- Create your own style for the CheckBox

  - Have a look here, how to style a CheckBox: [click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/checkbox-styles-and-templates)
- Set the `IsHitTestVisible` and `Focusable` properties to `False` and do not use the `IsEnabled` property.

`<CheckBox IsHitTestVisible="False" Focusable="False" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}"/>`

Comment: Thanks a lot, i like the second option.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to do it by intercepting the handler in the code behind (but generally i try to keep the code behind as thin as possible).

the XAML become :

```
<CheckBox IsEnabled="False" PreviewMouseDown="CheckBox_PreviewMouseDown" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

The xaml.cs become :

```
private void CheckBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: be careful, this does not work for keyboard navigation

Comment: Indeed... thanks a lot for awaring me with this detail. Anyway, i kept your full XAML solution, which is very elegant and simple.